# Transaction system Example not the JPA example

Tags: java, transactions, persistence, handler

I need an example of a system persistence of a state. a PersistenceHandler transaction system in java other than the JPA API. Are there any suggestions or examples please?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: i'll use mangoDB